# What to do when two shared libraries which uses different versions of the same 3rd party library?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I have a process **A** which uses two shared libraries: **libA.so** and **libB.so**. Because the two libraries were written by different people. Unfortunately **libA.so** uses version 1.0 of the 3rd party library **libD.so**. While **libB.so** uses version 2.0 of the library in static form **libD.a**. I know that if **libA.so** and **libA.so** use **libD.so**, some errors might happen because of the **Global Symbol Interpose**. But does this situation have the same problem too?

I know the link flag -Bsymbolic could be used on **libA.so** or **libB.so** to force the symbol resolving symbols with the library first. In order to make process **A** run correctly, both of the two libraries must be linked with this flag, am I right? However, I don't have the source code of **libA.so**. So I cannot re-link the **libA.so** again.

To be more general, if one process uses two 3rd party libraries, which contains another same 3rd party library. Will the same thing happen? Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: There is probably no general solution. You should exactly explain what `libA`, `libB`, `libD` really are. Maybe you could find a workaround for them in particular.

Comment: That's too bad, libB is the ITK which uses vnl(libD). The libA is unpublic library which uses vnl too. @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help you, but given the lack of information I'm hoping it at least sparks an idea or leads you to something similar.

This is an application that allows you to alter your shell settings on a per directory basis:
https://github.com/zimbatm/direnv

It sounds like you actually have an issue that would require you to recompile one of your libraries from source though. That's not ideal, but if there is no build using a compatible thirdparty version you might seek a completely different library to accomplish the original task.